# How to use Common Workflow Language (CWL) with viewflow?

Tags: django, bpmn.io, viewflow, common-workflow-language

Looking for ways to build workflows for viewflow that business analysts can use without writing code.  A graphical painter/editor like those for CWL may be just the ticket, but I have not found a way to use it.

If there is a tool for CWL or BPMN for graphically building workflows that can be consumed and executed with viewflow, please advise

Looking for a reference to a graphical tool to build viewflow workflows.

Comment: For BPMN 2.0 we use Activiti (-explorer) for painting workflows BPMN (which includes a wysiwyg diagram app), but it's a full fledged worfkflow solution (and requires Java, Tomcat, etc,). Flowable (a fork of Activiti) also has a BPMN workflow designer. Camunda modeler is another one. Sorry, no experience with CWL. (It seems that [rabix-composer](https://github.com/rabix/composer) does something like this.)

Comment: thanks @erny just what I was looking for, no preference for CWL just saw the screen shots.

Comment: I think BPMN and CWL are targeted at different audiences: BPMN for mixed human-machine workflows, and CWL for scientific data processing with sequences of command line like executions (I'm not sure about this), but the seems not to have too much user interaction.